# How to get some ids from hidden input and slice it with jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some ids from hidden input like:

`<input type="hidden" id="files" name="files" value="103,104,105">`

But when I try to add these ids into an array, it is just adding one string:

```
var id= $(this).parent('.added-files').attr("id");
var beforeIDs = $('#files').val(); 

if(beforeIDs == ''){    
    var photosIDs = [];
}else{
    var photosIDs = [beforeIDs];
}

console.log(photosIDs);
```

Its output:

```
["103,104,105"]
```

I just want to like this output

```
[103,104,105]
```

and with that I can remove easily remove id.

By the way, my whole code is:

```
var id = $(this).parent('.added-files').attr("id");
val = id.replace('uploaded_file_','');

var beforeIDs = $('#files').val();
if(beforeIDs == ''){
    var photosIDs = [];
}else{
    var photosIDs = [beforeIDs];
}

console.log(photosIDs);

for(var i = photosIDs.length; i--;) {
    if(photosIDs[i] ===val) { 
        photosIDs.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

console.log(photosIDs);
```

Where I am wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string on `,`.

This will also save you the checking-for-empty-value step.

```js
var beforeIDs = $('#files').val();

var photosIDs = beforeIDs.split(",");

console.log(photosIDs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="files" name="files" value="103,104,105">
```

Comment: Thank you Paul :) That's saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `.split()` to convert from a string to an array and, if necessary, you can use `.map()` to convert the array element types from string to numeric like so:

```
var beforeIDs = $(this).val(); 
var photosIDs = beforeIDs ? 
    beforeIDs.split(',').map(function(v) {
        return +v;
    }) : [];
console.log(photosIDs);
//OUTPUT: [103, 104, 105]
//W/O .map(): ["103", "104", "105"]
```

```js
$('input[type=hidden]').each(function() {
    var beforeIDs = $(this).val(); 
    var photosIDs = beforeIDs ? 
        beforeIDs.split(',').map(function(v) {
            return +v;
        }) : [];
    console.log(photosIDs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="files" name="files" value="103,104,105">
<input type="hidden" id="files1" name="files1" value="">
```